# How can I convert a colum of DATETIME type to string with linq

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have a table with three columns, ID, Date, Expenses, I am trying to search an int in Date column (Type of data in Date column is DateTime). For example, if the year is 1998 and the input is 8, the whole row should be displayed.

This is my code:

```
public ActionResult Get(string searchString)
{
     DateTime? startDate = new DateTime(2016, 1, 1);
     DateTime? endDate = new DateTime(2018, 12, 5);

     AccountingEntities db = new AccountingEntities();
     var expensesValues = from s in db.Expenses
                                 select s;

     if (startDate.HasValue)
     {
          expensesValues = expensesValues.Where(s => s.Date > startDate && s.Date < endDate);

          //This line gives error, I need to convert the s.Date to string so I can use Contains
          expensesValues = expensesValues.Where(s => s.Date.Contains(searchString));
     }
}
```

Comment: Give more examples of successful and unsuccessful matches ...

Comment: You are likely to find that keeping the date as a .NET `DateTime` in your code and then specifying the format when you render it on the page may work better. `DateTime` is a first class type (for example. If you subtract two of them, you get a `TimeSpan` representing the time period between the two instants in time

Comment: Honestly, I think you'd be better off ditching this requirement in favor of asking the user to provide a full information such as the range from and to and leaving it at that. 

To me it doesn't make sense to search a date for "8". About the only time that seems it would be useful would be: "what date did you make the transaction?" ... "uh. I don't remember. But I think it had an 8 in the date somewhere".

Comment: The answer is much more likely to be "in 1998" or "in August 1997 because..." and that's why systems that search dates just offer a range. You have a range, and I think it would be fine to leave it at that rather than "all of December 97 and then only dates where there is an 8 in it"..

Answer (score 1):

`System.DateTime` provides methods like `ToShortDateString()`.

With this, you get the date-portion of the DateTime object, formatted as a string. See [System.DateTime.ToShortDateString()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.toshortdatestring?view=net-5.0)

Comment: Are you sure it can be translated?

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Answer (score 0):

You can do so by calling `ToString()` on your date like so:

`expensesValues = expensesValues.Where(s => s.Date.ToString().Contains(searchString));`

Comment: Careful; it might use a format in the server that uses eg named months, and it then wouldn't find "8" in a date of eg 1999-08-01. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/sql-server/functions

Answer (score 0):

you can use the EF.Functions() method from entity framework core like below

```
var expensesValues = await db.Expenses.Where(w => EF.Functions.Like(w.Date.ToString(),"%" + searchString + "%")).ToListAsync();
```

This will do the filtering in the SQL server itself. Good perfomance and simple code

Comment: `LIKE` on a `date` column is unlikely to have good performance

Comment: @Charlieface, hi there, is it possible to share your benchmarks on this. thanks

Comment: https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2010/06/sargable-why-string-is-slow/ Note that for date columns it doesn't help to have the wildcard at the end because it forces an implicit conversion to text anyway

Answer (score 0):

Comments notwithstanding, if you do want to persist with this search I'd suggest doing it on the individual components, then you can be certain that EF will translate the C# to SQL and search what you expect

```
expensesValues = expensesValues.Where(s => 
  s.Date.Year.ToString().Contains(searchString) ||
  s.Date.Month.ToString().Contains(searchString) ||
  s.Date.Day.ToString().Contains(searchString)
);
```

If you need times continue the pattern

This also saves the db needlessly having to do a string concat, but if you're looking for outright performance I don't think there is a good option short of redefining how the search works